# Substract one file from another using SCSS

Tags: sass

I have one `common.scss` that is shared across multiple projects. This file have few lines that should be removed for new project. Is it possible to create file with CSS options that will be substracted from `common.scss`?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a boolean variable and wrap the lines of code in an if-statement. For example:

```
// common.scss

$include_extra_css: true;

// global css here

@if $include_extra_css {

   // special css here

}
```

Then, change the value of $include_extra_css accordingly per project.

However: it would be better if common.scss were a partial (_common.scss) that you import into another main Sass file. This way, you can use the !default flag on your variable and then change its value in whatever file imports it, rather than having to modify its value in common.scss for every project. (Note that it is bad practice to import a directly-compiling Sass file into another directly-compiling Sass file). Like so:

```
// common.scss

$include_extra_css: true !default;

// global css here

@if $include_extra_css {

   // special css here

}

// otherfile.scss

$include_extra_css: false;

@import "_common.scss";
```

Here's the Sass documentation on !default: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_